# "Email me" and "mail to me"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, prepositions, transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs

Why is it correct to say "email me", whereas with the word *mail* we say/write "mail to me"?

Comment: I cannot understand the question.  Are you claiming that “send me an e-mail” and “send a mail to me” are correct but “send me a mail” and “send an e-mail to me” are incorrect?  If so, I doubt that claim.

Comment: Now I realized that the title of the question contains yet another expression “email me,” which is not mentioned in the text of the question.  What is your question after all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only person I know who says "mail to me" is very much *not* a native speaker of English. "Write mail to me" is only marginally better.

> Mail me that package.
> Email me that report.

> Please [write|send] me a letter.
> Please [write|send] me an email.

> Write me!
> Email me!

> I got lots of mail.
> I got lots of letters.
> I got lots of emails.

> Nobody ever sends me any mail.
> Nobody ever sends me any email.
> Nobody ever writes [to] me.
> Nobody ever emails me.

> Please mail that card to me.
> Please email that picture to me.

As you can see, there *are* some differences between how the word *"mail"* is used vs. how the word *"email"* is used, but that difference **isn't** that *"mail"* takes *"to"* while *"email"* doesn't. It's more that *"email"* is used as the electronic equivalent of not just *"mail"*, but also *"letter"*.

Answer (score 2):

"Correct"?  That's just what many people use.  If that makes it "correct", so be it.

Some of us can't generate that construct.  We just just say *send me mail*, always. Well, or *mail me*, I guess.  I never say *email* at all, really.  *Mail* means email.  *Snail-mail* is postal mail.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I am not omniscient. I see things only as they come to me, not seeing everything everywhere everywhen.

Comment: Strange, you've never seen Scotm post two answers on the same question?  Because he's posted two, and three answers several times, spread over a period of months, not days. (deleting first comment)